# How to resolve the 'can't pickle lxml.etree.QName objects ' when using zeep library with python for a SOAP API request?

Tags: python-3.x, soap, python-3.6, soap-client, zeep

I am trying to post a SOAP API request using zeep library + python. But it fails with some error. 
The SOAP request looks like this.

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:att="http://www.front.com/front/attributes" xmlns:web="http://webservices.front.trapedza.com">
       <soapenv:Header>
          <web:soapheader>
             <!--Optional:-->
             <web:authentication>
                <web:userName>user1</web:userName>
                <web:password>password1</web:password>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <web:RestUrl></web:RestUrl>
             </web:authentication>
             <web:SHeader>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <att:correlationID></att:correlationID>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <att:zone>SAFE</att:zone>
                <att:autoAuthorize></att:autoAuthorize>
             </web:SHeader>
          </web:soapheader>
       </soapenv:Header>
       <soapenv:Body>
          <web:USERDETAILS_SRV>
             <web:requestPayload>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <generalParam>'UNIQUEID=TID123;
                FIRSTNAME= JOHNNY;
                LASTNAME= DEP'
    </generalParam>
                <!--Optional:-->
                <configParam>CHECK_REQD=N;ACTION=A</configParam>             
             </web:requestPayload>
          </web:USERDETAILS_SRV>
       </soapenv:Body>
    </soapenv:Envelope>
```

The code that I written for the sending the request is :

```
from zeep import Client,Settings
from zeep import xsd

def callMethod():
    url="http://10.111.3.112:8080/services/USERDETAILS_SRVWS?wsdl"
    settings = Settings(strict=False, xml_huge_tree=True)
    client = Client(url, settings=settings)
header = zeep.xsd.Element(
            'soapheader',
            zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                zeep.xsd.Element(
                    'authentication',
                    zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                        zeep.xsd.Element('userName',zeep.xsd.String()),
                        zeep.xsd.Element('password',zeep.xsd.String())
                    ])                
                ),
                zeep.xsd.Element(
                    'SHeader',
                    zeep.xsd.ComplexType([
                    zeep.xsd.Element('zone',zeep.xsd.String())
                       ])                
                )
            ])
        )
header_value = header(authentication={'userName':'user1','password':'password1'},SHeader={'zone': 'SAFE'})


request ={'generalParam': 'UNIQUEID=TID123; FIRSTNAME= JOHNNY;
LASTNAME= DEP'},{'configParam': 'CHECK_REQD=N;ACTION=A'}

with client.settings(raw_response=True):
        client.set_default_soapheaders(header)
        res = client.service.USERDETAILS_SRV(requestData)
        print(res)

callMethod()
```

On executing the above code it gives me the below error.

```
    res = client.service.USERDETAILS_SRV(requestData)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\zeep\proxy.py", line 45, in __call__
    kwargs,
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 119, in send
    operation, args, kwargs, client=client, options=options
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\bindings\soap.py", line 68, in _create
    serialized = operation_obj.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\definitions.py", line 215, in create
    return self.input.serialize(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 59, in serialize
    header = self._serialize_header(headers_value, nsmap)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\site-packages\zeep\wsdl\messages\soap.py", line 326, in _serialize_header
    headers_value = copy.deepcopy(headers_value)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\copy.py", line 180, in deepcopy
    y = _reconstruct(x, memo, *rv)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\copy.py", line 280, in _reconstruct
    state = deepcopy(state, memo)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\copy.py", line 150, in deepcopy
    y = copier(x, memo)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\copy.py", line 240, in _deepcopy_dict
    y[deepcopy(key, memo)] = deepcopy(value, memo)
  File "C:\Python3\lib\copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)
TypeError: can't pickle lxml.etree.QName objects
```

I believe the code isn't correct. Please help me in fixing the code, and to add the header along with request so that I get a response for the same.

Comment: is it possible that you post the output of `python -mzeep http://10.111.3.112:8080/services/USERDETAILS_SRVWS?wsdl` ? then we will be able to help you in better and quicker way. thanks

Comment: @Tarique, It's my company api, due to security issues can't do that.... Please could you let me know what are you looking out there in -mzeep

Comment: what is the definition of `USERDETAILS_SRV` method ?

Comment: @Tarique , Please find the method definition below. Service: USERDETAILS_SRVWSService
     Port: USERDETAILS_SRVWSPort (Soap11Binding: {http://USERDETAILS_SRVWS}USERDETAILS_SRVWSSoapBinding)
         Operations:
            USERDETAILS_SRV(requestPayload: ns2:generalParam, _soapheaders={soapheader: ns0:soapheader}) -> responsePayload: ns2:rsPayload, ErrorResponse: ns3:ErrorResponse